# How to use imm8 in SSE?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, x86, sse, simd

I have a `__m128i` register filled with 32 bit ints. I want to extract the 4th element from the register.

For example,
if

```
int extract;
__m128i register = _mm_set_epi32(3,2,1,0);
```

then I want 'extract' to have the value 3.

It seems that _mm_extract_epi32() should do the work. However, it has a imm8 parameter.

---

Img:
[description on Intel's website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En5Uq.png)

---

I just don't understand how `imm8` works (or would work in this case).
Can someone please elaborate on how to use imm8 as a parameter?

Comment: Did you try passing 3 (or maybe 8-3 if the order is reversed) as value for that argument? It doesn't have to be complicated just because the notation is a bit unusual.

Comment: Tried it, wasn't working before. Maybe it was a #include file that was missing. It's good now, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`imm8` needs to be a literal constant, i.e. a number that is known at compile-time. Note also that `register` is a reserved word. E.g.

```
#include <smmintrin.h> // SSE 4.1

__m128i v = _mm_set_epi32(3, 2, 1, 0); // initialise v to 4 x 32 bit int values
int extract = _mm_extract_epi32(v, 3); // extract element 3
```

Comment: Right, made the change. Sorry, had 16 bits in mind when I wrote it.
I tried what you said before, it wasn't working. Works now. Guess I had the #include<smmintrin.h> missing somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Some compilers may require a *literal* constant, but most accept any `constexpr`, and some anything that that evaluates to a constant at compile time, even if it wasn't declared `constexpr`.  (gcc compiles `int pos = 3;` / `_mm_extract_epi32(v, pos);`, but only with optimization enabled.)  It turns out MSVC requires you to declare it `const` or `constexpr` even with `-Ox`.  https://godbolt.org/g/UbokBt.  (You should definitely use `const` or preferably `constexpr` if you want to give a symbolic name to something you're going to pass as an imm8 arg to an intrinsic.)